# How do I handle partial JSON in a JsonConverter while using DeserializeAsync on a stream?

Tags: c#, system.text.json, .net-5

I'm getting `InvalidOperationException: Cannot skip tokens on partial JSON. Either get the whole payload and create a Utf8JsonReader instance where isFinalBlock is true or call TrySkip.` in my JsonConverter.

- Using .NET 5.0 Preview 7
- Using System.Text.Json
- Console app

Code:

```
record Banana(int A, int B, int C);

class BananaConverter : JsonConverter<Banana>
{
    [return: MaybeNull]
    public override Banana Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                reader.Skip();
            }
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return new(1, 2, 3);
// EDIT: ^-- Admittedly, this logic is a bit wrong, but not important for the question
    }
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Banana value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
}

static async Task Main()
{
    var bananas = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Select(x => new Banana(x, x + 1, x + 2));
    var bytenanas = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(bananas);
    var ms = new MemoryStream(bytenanas);
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { Converters = { new BananaConverter() } };
    var brokenanas = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Banana[]>(ms, options);
}
```

.csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="5.0.0-preview.7.20364.11" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

`.Skip()` is what throws the exception.

If I deserialize using `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Banana[]>(bytenanas, options);` instead, then there's no problem.

I assume what happens is the `DeserializeAsync` reads things into buffers, and of course isn't aligned to json object boundaries.  So how do I handle incomplete JSON in my JsonConverter?  Or am I taking the wrong approach altogether?

EDIT:

```
[return: MaybeNull]
public override Banana Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    var old = reader;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
        {
            if (!reader.TrySkip())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Couldn't skip");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
        {
            return new(1, 2, 3);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Couldn't read");
    reader = old;
    return default;
}
```

I've tried this `Read` implementation too.  While it "works", I have no idea why.  Neither `Couldn't skip` nor `Couldn't read` are ever hit.  `.TrySkip` never returns false.  So why would `.Skip` throw that exception?

LAST EDIT (with solution - or at least, mystery solved!):

Reading through the implementation of `Utf8JsonReader` on github, I found that `Skip` is not even *attempted* when isFinalBlock is false.  I had expected the logic to be basically `if (!TrySkip()) throw new Explosion();`, but instead, it just explodes.  Literally, the exception telling me `call TrySkip` was... being... well, literal :)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on .NET Core 3.1.5, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/g4FPbd.  There was a plan to add `async` support for converters, see [Serializer support for easier object and collection converters #1562](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1562) but I'm not sure what actually got done.  Have to read through [New serializer converter model for objects and collections #2259](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/2259) it seems...

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue about this.  [New serializer converter model for objects and collections #2259](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/2259) states, *No public APIs have changed with this PR - changes were made to be internal for now.*.

Comment: [`JsonConverter<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonConverterOfT.cs#L86) now has an `internal virtual bool OnTryRead(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ref ReadStack state, [MaybeNull] out T value)` method but it's `internal virtual` so you can't override it.

Comment: Okay - will open an issue!  Thanks :D

Comment: OK, I can *guess* why that works.  `Utf8JsonReader` tracks state and remembers whether end of data was reached prematurely, thus the `Read()` method doesn't need to return this fact.  All the reader needs to do is to return... what?  How does it persist state between calls?  Or does `Utf8JsonReader` somehow get rewound to beginning of object?  I can't find any documentation on it.  In your case though you don't actually use the values read from the file so you avoid the issue of persisting state.

Comment: I read through DeserializeAsync in System.Text.Json on github.  Looks like it is tracking bytes consumed, which is why I tried my second version.  But the important code in the second version never gets hit, so... yeah.  Opening an issue now.

Comment: Did you ever open an issue about this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already in the question description, but to make it easier for others to find the answer, I'm putting it here, with enough details to make it understandable.

**The short answer is:** Call [`TrySkip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.tryskip) instead of [`Skip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.skip).

That's it. You don't even need to check for the return value of `TrySkip()`, because, in a custom converter, all the required JSON data for the current scope is always passed to the `Utf8JsonReader` ([as mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to#:%7E:text=You%20don%27t%20have%20to%20worry%20about%20handling%20partial%20data%2C%20as%20the%20serializer%20passes%20all%20the%20data%20for%20the%20current%20JSON%20scope.)).

If the `Utf8JsonReader` instance is created from partial JSON, the `Skip` method will always throw an exception! In contrast, the `TrySkip` method, correctly tries to skip the node, including the children, and only fails if there is not enough data to continue (which will not happen in our case).

I know, there is something wrong with this design decision!

Comment: You _could_ have instead asked the OP to answer his own question, instead of putting it in the question body....

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes, I could, but I thought it is worth to add additional information for clarification. I don't care about my answer being accepted or upvoted, but I don't want other people lose hours on the issue.